# Angular ng-if not updating on value change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

When a person clicks No on whether or not they want to trade in their car it is supposed to remove that element and add the other element asking if they have a car to trade in.  However, when they click it does not remove the element but simply makes the car variable empty. It seems simple enough... don't know why it's not working.

```
  <div class="inner-box" ng-if="car.length > 0">
    <p class="lite">Would you like to trade in your</p>
    <p class="heavy">{{car}} ?</p>
    <a href="#" class="blue">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="car = ''">No</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-box" ng-if="car.length == 0">
    <p class="heavy">Do you have a trade in ?</p>
    <a href="#" class="blue">Yes</a>
    <a href="#">No</a>
  </div>
```

I've seen another question about this on here but their problem was that their nf-if wasn't a condition.

Comment: please share you angular code and it will be better if you can create a Fiddle for it.

Comment: please share code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a controller function for delete car

```
<div class="inner-box" ng-if="car">
    <p class="lite">Would you like to trade in your</p>
    <p class="heavy">{{car}} ?</p>
    <a href="#" class="blue">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="deleteCar();">No</a>
</div>
<div class="inner-box" ng-if="!car">
    <p class="heavy">Do you have a trade in ?</p>
    <a href="#" class="blue">Yes</a>
    <a href="#">No</a>
</div>
```

------JS---

```
$scope.deleteCar = function(){
    $scope.car = '';
};
```

Comment: using ng-show may be a solution but what if there is a requirement to use ng-if only. because i think you might be aware of the difference between the two.

Comment: That will simply hide the element though.  I wanted to remove it

Comment: Yes, this works now, thank you.  However not the way it was.  I sending car back in the function and deleting it I believe was deleting a local variable.  Instead I used $scope.car = '';